# How to specify boundary coordinates for raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates

I am using QGIS for loading my raster image as raster layer. I want to combine it with my vector layer, which is GEOJSON file. When I load GEOJSON file, it's placed on its coordinates, but the raster picture is placed to coordinates 0,0. Is there a way, how to move the raster "under" my vector layer - I mean how to move it and scale it? Or better - I know its corners coordinates - can I anyhow assign these coordinates to the raster layer, so it's correctly displayed on its position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to georeference your raster using the Qgis georeferencing tool (raster < georeference). Follow these steps :

- load your raster file
- select the right CRS (the one for which you have coordinates)
- create points clicking on the raster and entering the coordinates.

4 points is not really enough, if you can, add 2 or 3 more to be sure that it's properly georeferenced.

Comment: 4 Points are totally fine if you just need to assign the 4 corners and transform linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do I need a plugin for this? I have no Raster -> georeference menu option (I use version 2.18). The only available options under Raster menu are: raster calculator, align rasters, projections, conversion, extraction, analysis, miscellanous, gdaltools settings.

Comment: Yes, it's the Georeferencer plugin : http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html

Comment: Thanks, the issue was the plugin was installed, but it hasn't been enabled.